# Retornar dados de uma classe para index

Tags: php

Estou colocando em prática *PHP* Orientado à Objetos e estou desenvolvendo um *CRUD* de alunos.

Tenho uma classe para contar a quantidade de alunos no banco. E eu queria pegar o retorno da função que conta os alunos e mandar esse resultado para index, mas estou com dificuldade em fazer isso.

classe MostraAluno.php:

```
<?php

class MostraAluno
{
    protected $nome, $media;
    public $dns = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=alunos';
    public $user = 'root';
    public $pass = 'vertrigo';
    public $pdo;

    public function __construct()
    {
        try {
            $this->pdo = new PDO($this->dns, $this->user, $this->pass);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            die('Erro de conexao com o banco de dados: ' . $e->getMessage());
        }
    }

    public function contaAluno()
    {
        $count = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM usuarios ORDER BY nome ASC";

        $stmt_count = $this->pdo->prepare($count);
        $stmt_count->execute();
        $total = $stmt_count->fetchColumn();

        return $total;
    }
}
```

E o index.php:

```
<?php

require_once 'core/MostraAluno.php';

$mostraAluno = new MostraAluno();

$alunos = $mostraAluno->mostraAluno();
$totAlunos = $mostraAluno->contaAluno();

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/css/style.css">

<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Notas - Alunos</title>
</head>
<body>

<!--
=======================================================================
                                NAVBAR
=======================================================================
-->
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
<div id="inicio" class="container-fluid">

  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#inicio"><b>Sistema de notas</b></a>
  </div>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="cadastrar.php"><u>Cadastrar novo aluno</u></a></li>
      </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Perfil <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="core/logout.php">Sair</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>

<!--
=======================================================================
                                CORPO
=======================================================================
-->

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12" style="background-color: ">
  <center><h4 class="bg-info"><b>Total de alunos: <?php echo $totAlunos; ?></b></h4></center>
    </div>
</div>
```

Quando executado a index aparece somente o texto 'Total de alunos:' e nao aparece o retorno do método.

No arquivo `MostraAluno` eu retirei o método `mostraAluno()`, pois minha dúvida é somente com o método `contaAluno()`.

Alguém poderia me dizer onde estou errando? Estou começando agora a colocar em prática *PHP OO* e estou com dificuldades em retornar os valores dos métodos para outros arquivos.

Comment: sua tabela `usuarios` possui dados?

Comment: Porque eu testei seu codigo e funcionou

Comment: Sim. possui dois registros

Comment: coloca esse codigo no seu index e veja que erro mostra:  ` ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_erros',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL); `

Comment: Encontrei o erro... o nome da tabela no banco estava USUARIS

Sem a letra O de USUARIOS  -_-

Comment: pronto. Que bom que deu certo

Comment: @Gabriel veja isto: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/editing se as pessoas melhoram sua pergunta você deveria aceitar a mudança. Algum motivo para ter rejeitado?

Comment: Sim. Mudanças como alterar uma frase para itálico, ao meu ver, é irrelevante. Não mudará nada com relação ao entendimento do tópico e da questão levantada. E outra, as mudanças só começaram a serem feitas após o @adventistaam ja ter se manifestado em relação a minha dúvida, ou seja, ele entendeu o que foi questionado no tópico! Então não vi nenhum motivo para correção, principalmente correções de colocar frases em itálico.

Comment: @Gabriel ele mudou bem mais do que italico, ele corrigiu acentuação e pontuação, o que é totalmente aceitável e útil e melhora sim a leitura. O Saul também editou outra pergunta sua que você rejeitou e era uma boa edição, ele removeu redundâncias (como no título) e "saudações" desnecessárias. Entenda mais sobre o assunto em https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/846/3635 ;)

Answer (score 1):

Apesar de ja ter encontrado o erro. Tem um outro modo de fazer caso você queria usar um dia:

```
    $stmt_count = $this->pdo->prepare($count);
    $stmt_count->execute();
    $total = $stmt_count-> rowCount(); // aqui ele conta o total
```

O bom de fazer dessa forma, é que você pode fazer a seleção de todos os alunos(no caso) e apenas usar o `rowCount();` para contar a quantidade total, sem a necessidade de fazer duas conexões.